# Pig : Cogroup How to avoid Blank values

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to pig.
While doing a `COGROUP` i came across issue.
I am trying to do a `COGROUP` on two files. Keys which i am using for `COGROUP` having a null values.

Below are my input files :
Input_file_1 :

```
a|b||
e|f||
```

Input_file_2 :

```
a|b||
e|f||
```

I am using all the four columns as a key while doing a `COGROUP`. (Last two columns are blank)

My expected output is two records, but i am getting four records as a output.
Can anyone please help how to avoid blank values while doing a `COGROUP` in PIG.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you share some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null values are handled very differently in PIG.

As per Alan Gates, the author of Book [Programming Pig](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch06.html#cogroup) says

> cogroup handles null values in the keys similarly to group and unlike
>   join. That is, all records with a null value in the key will be collected together.

Thus the output of COGROUP would be

```
((a,b,,),{(a,b,,)},{})
((a,b,,),{},{(a,b,,)})
((e,f,,),{(e,f,,)},{})
((e,f,,),{},{(e,f,,)})
```

In your case, you have to go for JOIN instead of COGROUP. Thus giving you following result

```
(a,b,,,a,b,,)
(e,f,,,e,f,,)
```

Then generate required values.